# How to connect python flask code to html code

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I am trying to have users upload photos and then have those photos when submitted, go into a folder in pythonaywhere. I realized that even though the website is working, it seems as though my html and python code are not connected, hence why when I upload a pdf even if that is not an allowed extension, my webapp takes it in but it doesn't process through the conditions on my python code.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/HassanSherien/mysite/Shape_Image'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            flash(file)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))


    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("overview_main_page.html", comments=Comment.query.all())
    return

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>') #, #methods=["GET", "POST"])
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

```
  <div class="w3-panel">
    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px">
      <div class="w3-third">
       <form action="http://hassansherien.pythonanywhere.com" method="post">
           <input type="file" name="file" value="fileupload" id="file_upload">
           <input type='submit' />
```

Comment: The action on your HTML form doesn't post to the view you showed -- its action is set to the route '/', not to '/upload'.

Comment: I think I have figured it out, thank you! @GilesThomas